# Stopping MaskedEditExtender from validating input in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have an asp.net textbox and a MaskedEditExtender control attached to it. The textbox is used for date input. The MaskedEditExtender has MaskType="Date" Mask="99/99/9999".

When the form is submitted with an invalid date, the browser shows a Javascript error "... string was not recognized as a valid datetime".

I know why the error shows up. Is there a way to use the extender to just control what the user enters and not validate or convert the input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on the text box you and set up a keypress function.

Validate if the key pressed is a number
String.fromCharCode(event.which) or event.keycode (ie or FF)

Then can check that the text box is contains valid code and format.

If invalid you can set to a default that is valid or just prevent the keypress by using 
preventDefault()

if invalid format can disable the submit button also ....

Good luck

Comment: Are saying not to use the MaskedEditExtender? Otherwise that's the job of the control so that I don't have to do all this work. That's what maskedits do. Plus I want to just the mask itself.

Comment: Never mind. It was a code behind exception in my code which wasn't caught. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Stop the form from submitting with an invalid date. Use a MaskedEditValidator

Answer (score 0):

Don't specify mask type as "Date", that should stop this error.